# Gravatar links on "Filtered Questions" page are not HTTPS

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, gravatar, ssl

Gravatar links on the "Top Network Askers" sidebar of the [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) page are not HTTPS links. Gravatar links elsewhere on the site seem to use HTTPS links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the recent [official announcement of https support](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/), this problem appears to have been fixed.